# Rspec parallel_test controller spec random fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

While running **parallel_rspec spec** random fails with controller any solution.

In Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'parallel_tests'  
end
```

My Spec execution like this

```
name@root:/project# parallel_rspec spec/controllers/
4 processes for 21 specs, ~ 5 specs per process

Randomized with seed 3503

Randomized with seed 41377
 0/62 |>                                                       |  ETA: ??:??:?? 
Randomized with seed 43603
 0/50 |>                                                       |  ETA: ??:??:?? 
Randomized with seed 61169
 3/62 |==>                                                     |  ETA: 00:08:03 
  1) Admin::ReportingsController when signed-in non-admin GET #instance_reports redirects to root_url
     Failure/Error: expect( response ).to redirect_to root_url

       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://xxx/> but was a redirect to <http://yyyy>.
       Expected "http://xxxx/" to be === "http://xxxx/code".
     # ./spec/support/functions.rb:12:in `expect_root_redirect'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/reportings_controller_spec.rb:25:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/factory_bot.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:100:in `cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/support/factory_bot.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

like this fails randomly.

IF we run with below command its works fine.

```
rspec spec/controllers
```

Note :

- Single DB connected while execution.
- Except controller everything works fine.
- most are like json related conditions are faild.

Comment: Do you use multiple databases? One for each thread?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this? We need to be able to reproduce the problem (or *at least* see enough code to spot a potential mistake) in order to give a meaningful response.

Comment: Please find the above input, anything required more than that!

Comment: Running with 1 file its works fine but more than one its fills like **ActiveRecord::Deadlocked** , **JSON errors**, **response code mismatching**   etc..

but models and other test cases works fine using **parallel_rspec** command (both single file and folder as well)

If we run with below command it works










> parallel_rspec -n 1 -t rspec spec/controllers



but multi processes alone not working for controller.

Comment: One possibility is that your tests have side-effects, try running `bundle exec rspec --seed 61169` or replace `61169` by any seed number that failed. Rspec will attempt to find the minimal set that cause your suite to fail, it's possible that one test sets an environment variable and another test uses it by accident.

Comment: @DaniloCabello this won't work with parallel tests. Seed won't control which of two concurrent requests will be accepted first by the app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the the test assumes one state of the app, but it was probably changed by some concurrent request. (I'd bet that session is shared, and when testing your controller you think the person logged in is X, but it's Y).

Make sure each of the parallel runs are separated, it seems like all your tests are connecting to the same DB

> Single DB connected while execution.
>   This makes sense in single threaded apps, because it's cleaned after each example. But when running in parallel it can be a mess, and you can never be sure what's in the DB.

Did you change you DB config like this:

```
test:
  database: yourproject_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
```

If you miss that - that's your u